# Comprobar si el ID existe mediante método GET

Tags: php

hace días vengo comiendome la cabeza con este problema que seguramente debe ser fácil de resolver pero estoy bastante atorado, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario envie un número de ID inexistente por medio de parametro GET, lo redireccione a una página de error, pero no sé como comprobar si el usuario enviado por GET existe en la BD. Tengo esto por ahora:

```
    <?php
include "models/conexion.php";
$ID = $_GET[("ID")];

$consulta = "SELECT ID FROM trabajos_finales WHERE ID = '$ID'";

if (!isset($ID) || empty($ID)) {
    header("Location: vista-administrador.php?mensaje=error");
}
```

(estoy usando PDO), gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Por qué no compruebas si tu ```$consulta``` obtiene datos o no? Aquí tienes el manual de como ejecutar una sentencia PDO, y posterior podrías comprobar si trae datos o no: https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.exec.php

Comment: Léete [ask] para aprender a realizar buenas preguntas. En esta caso es muy confusa, pues no sabemos lo que quieres, es decir, 1) ¿quieres saber si un ID enviado por GET existe en una tabla de una base de datos? Eso es lo que indica tu título... 2) ¿o más bien saber si el usuario que ha enviado un ID mediante GET existe en la base de datos?  Eso dices en el cuerpo de tu pregunta... o 3) ¿Quieres redireccionar a una página de error a cualquier usuario que envie una ID inexistente por GET? Tambien en el cuerto de tu pregunta. ... o 4) ¿Ese ID es de usuario o de trabajo final? En tu SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código está mal planteado desde el punto de vista lógico (verificación de los empty a posteriori) y no estás obteniendo el dato de la consulta SQL. Tampoco refieres bien las claves para obtener el dato del GET.

Además de eso, el código es vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*.

Y hay varias lagunas, situaciones que escapan y que no queda claro lo que se deba hacer en tales casos.

Podrías lograr lo que quieres de este modo (las lagunas lógicas las he resuelto en forma de `$msg` y haciendo `echo` de los mismos, probablemente debas refinar la lógica):

```
/*
  No se usa paréntesis para claves de arrays 
  */
$ID = $_GET["ID"] ?? null;

if ($ID) {
  include "models/conexion.php";
  /*
    En primer lugar verificamos la conexión 
    aquí asumimos que tu conexión se llama $pdo, 
    si no es así, lo cambias por como se llame
    */
  if ($pdo)  {
    /*
      Usaremos consultas preparadas para dar seguridad al código
      Y usaremos una consulta de conteo para verificar la existencia
      */
      $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trabajos_finales WHERE ID =:ID";
      $stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(":ID",$ID,PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->execute();
      if($stmt->fetchColumn()) {
        /*
          El registro existe...
          ¿Qué debe ocurrir aquí?
          */
        $msg="El registro existe. ¿Qué debe ocurrir en este caso?";
        echo $msg;
      } else {
        header("Location: vista-administrador.php?mensaje=error");
        exit();        
      }
    } else {
      $msg="No hay conexión... ¿Qué debe ocurrir en este caso?";
      echo $msg;
    }
} else {
    $msg="No se posteó ningún ID... ¿Qué debe ocurrir en este caso?";
    echo $msg;    
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funcionó perfectamente y sí, sabia que tenia esas fallas y que me podian inyectar codigo SQL pero queria algo rápido y funcional porque es para una presentación en mi instituto, lo de preparar la consulta, ejecutarla y realizar un fetch también lo intenté pero por varias razones seguro no me salia, el tuyo esta perfecto y entendí casi todo, pd: soy nuevo acá y no sé si esta es la forma de contestar a la respuesta, tampoco sé como cerrar el tema jajaj saludos!

Comment: @MarceloSanchez este sitio no funciona como un foro, la forma de marcar el problema como resuelto es activando la flecha gris a la izquierda de la respuesta que consideres ha resuelto el problema. También puedes votar positivamente activando la flecha que apunta hacia arriba, o negativamente, activando la flecha que apunta hacia abajo. Revisa los enlaces del sitio para comprender cómo funciona.